# Unable to extend BaseCommandController in Eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and I am trying to extend `BaseCommandController` but Eclipse doesn't show it. I can extend `AbstractController` but not `BaseCommandController`.  I have added all jar files from spring-framework 4.2.2.RELEASE.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add some code sample or error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to extend `BaseCommandController` because it is deprecated since [Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html) and got removed in Spring 4.

The Spring way is now to use annotations as mentioned in the deprecation comment:

> `@deprecated` as of Spring 3.0, in favor of annotated controllers

You should have a look at the [Getting Started guide of Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) where you can find a good example of the [`@Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) annotation